# Return details of DB record created in Mule

Tags: database, api, mule

When using the Generic Database Connector in Mule is there a way that when you insert a new record in to a database, the ID (or entire record) is returned back to the flow as the payload?

My use case is fairly common in that I'm exposing an API which results in a record being generated in a database. The response to that API call needs to include the ID of the record created.

I've looked through the Mule documentation and haven't found anything. Hopefully I'm overlooking something very obvious here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating an ID in database and later retrieving it, I'd recommend generating a `UUID` inside your mule application using `java.util.Random` and using that to insert record in db. This way you already have the ID and no need to get it from db.

Answer (score 1):

Plain insert query should just give you the count of rows inserted and not the record itself.

You can write a stored procedure that gets inserts the record and then returns as output. Then call this stored procedure from Mule Database connector and you will have output of stored procedure as the payload.