# mule returning primary key on successful insert

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Hi there I'm new to Mule and I needed pointer on how to process records. I'm trying to perform an operation where I insert a new record into one table and if the record is inserted successfully, obtain the primary key and insert it into another table where the primary key is part of the foreign key.

I don't know which connector or component to use to check if an insert was successful so that I can insert the primary key into another table.

My primary key is a uuid generated as a variable. I tried returning the GUID from sql server using using the following documentation but it didn't work. Any help or pointers on either question will help.

https://doctorjw.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/mule-and-getting-the-generated-id-of-a-newly-inserted-row/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800675/return-details-of-db-record-created-in-mule/35805943#35805943

Answer (score 1):

If you want a DB-generated Id, you can use two DB blocks, saving a variable between them:

1st DB block: generate an unique Id throw a sequence, in example:

```
select GENERAID_ESB.nextval from dual
```

Save variable (Session or Flow, depending on your required scope for it):

```
#[payload.get(0).nextval]
```

2nd DB block: insert your record in DB with unique id saved, in example:

```
INSERT INTO ESB_TABLE values(#[(sessionVars.'idTable')],
#[message.outboundProperties.'yourInformation'])**
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this creates a race condition if you don't use `Transactions`

Answer (score 0):

In mule 4.4, it is very simple:
1, set 'true' in Advanced-auto generate key[image]

2, the return payload has the key:
[image]